# Узнать размер изображения

Tags: python, изображения, pil

Форумчане, не могли бы вы подсказать, как с помощью "Python" и сопуствующих библиотек узнать размер (координаты "X" и "Y") какого-либо изображения?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

При помощи PIL узнать размер можно так:

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open("logo.jpg")
(width, height) = im.size
```